# Django form: Check for unique name

Tags: django, forms

In my form I want to check if the descriptor name is unique for this project.

Models.py

```
class Descriptor (models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

forms.py

```
class DescriptorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Descriptor
        fields = ('name','project')
        widgets = {'project': forms.HiddenInput()}

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        project = self.fields['project']
        if Descriptor.objects.filter(project=project, name__iexact=name).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Descriptor with this name already exists")
        return name
```

I am getting

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
 'ModelChoiceField'
```

Without `project = self.fields['project']` and `project=project` thec check works, but for all Descriptors and not just the ones connected to this Project. What do i have to change to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `fields` you should use `cleaned_data` to get `project` value inside `clean_name` method, also change fields order to make project available during name validation:

```
class DescriptorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Descriptor
        fields = ('project', 'name')
        widgets = {'project': forms.HiddenInput()}

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        project = self.cleaned_data['project']
        if Descriptor.objects.filter(project=project, name__iexact=name).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Descriptor with this name already exists")
        return name
```

`self.fields['project']` return field class itself, not it's value.

Comment: I actually tryed this allready, it returns a `KeyError: 'project'`. But thx for the fast reply

Comment: @Rubick also change fields order. Chech updares.

Comment: @Rubick I suspect `'project'` is not present in `cleaned_data` because the widget is of type `HiddenInput`

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your model, you could use the [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together) `Meta` attribute to achieve the uniqueness check.

```
class Descriptor (models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('project', 'name'),
        )
```

And with this your form would be reduced to:

```
class DescriptorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Descriptor
        fields = ('project', 'name')
        widgets = {
            'project': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

---

On a (important) side not: you should **NOT** use `default='1'` in your `ForeignKey`, because it expects an `Project` instance, not a string.

Comment: I can change the model. Is this a better solution than checking uniqueness via the form?And if so, why? Thanks for the sidenote, i deleted the default.

Comment: @Rubick `unique_together` creates a database index automatically, which makes checking uniqueness faster. Also, if your form does not catch the duplication, the database will not allow the insertion and raise an error when calling the models `save()` method.